# Does the C# switch statment need a break;

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Is C# true to C++, needing a `break;` per `case:`? *..**Default is fall-thru** - Unlike VB*

OR will it automatically break out of a case once found? *..**Default is break** - Like VB*

---

**Edit:** So it is a combination of both, ***Default is none*** - You have to specify either break; or goto;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every *case* needs to have either a *break;* or *goto case* statement in C#

Answer (score 3):

You use a `break` in C#, just like in C++. However, if you *omit* the break you must replace it with another other control transfer (e.g. `goto case 1;`).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It requires the break or you'll get a compiler error. You can have multiple cases with one block of code but control cannot fall through to the next case.

Answer (score 0):

You need some statement, either break or goto.